# How could someone swapped more tokens than a token's maximum supply?

Tags: transactions, uniswap

I recently found a rugpull incident which is unusual to me.

The token is already locked for its maximum supply:

Contract creation: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x02f4ff68534bd46d4ddcc9c90919fffa7c35e9d86bb5a61b6ddd8e00d1e1aaa4

add liquidity contract:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xef766ea79acea841460b9c480e1012bfee9292701ce58cdb031b164257f24436

lock contract:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x532ca59aa3bf1d6f222a723c792d6442cc97d9d460dcfa2f4b27d3306bb306fa

The weird transaction:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x9ee1dfa2adc8fa59048f3b86d8b60786e91dce6bbc3d1800c067f235b364b195

The maximum supply is 1,000,000,000, so how could that address swapped 1,000,000,000,000,000 tokens? And no transfer events to the address ever happened before. Is the token just appear in the wallet out of thin air? Is it something in the smart contract?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try to guess it by checking that tx, https://etherscan.io/tx/0x9ee1dfa2adc8fa59048f3b86d8b60786e91dce6bbc3d1800c067f235b364b195
and the EOA, 0x1D1F6b06Ec378dF75142c950c5009e5a8F017B80.

Since this address didn't get any token before the swap, we can strongly suspect the `transferFrom` is not a typical ERC20 implementation (Because unsiwap's `swap` calls `transferFrom` under the hood).

If you decompile the byptecode of that contract, you can verify that the `transferFrom` is a modified malicious version with hard coded attacker address(0x1D1F6b06Ec378dF75142c950c5009e5a8F017B80) in the implementation. https://app.dedaub.com/decompile?md5=3c594e21e2288da210740ced0b1594a4

Because etherscan.io is using event log (`Transfer`) to present you the ERC20 transfer transactions. As long as the attacker passes a huge number to the event, you can see this kind of weird behavior.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks for the explanation